# Grouping by a count of a field in a subquery

Tags: sql, group-by

Assume these tables, with those fields:

**History:**

```
postID, viewerID
```

**Posts:**

```
postID, posterID
```

Now this query:

```
SELECT postID FROM history
WHERE postID IN (SELECT postID FROM Posts WHERE posterID IN (10,20,30)
AND viewerID=50
```

Will return all postIDS from posters 10,20 & 30, that viewer 50 has viewed.

What I'm after is a "group-by" that will be according to
the number of results of any posts per posterID.

For example, the results of the currently described query can have

```
100,200,300,300,300,100,400, 700, 500
```

Let's say the first 7 results are from Poster 10 and the last 2 are from poster 20 - 
So I need a result of:

```
posterID   viewsNum
10         7
20         2
```

My SQL level is intermediate, so it is not immediately clear for me how to achieve this,
sorry if there's a 'simple' answer hiding inside :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need here, is just a `GROUP BY` with an aggregate function `COUNT()`, and `JOIN` the two tables instead. Something like:

```
SELECT 
  PosterID, 
  COUNT(postID) viewsNum
FROM history h 
INNER JOIN Posts p ON h.postID = p.PostID
WHERE p.posterID IN (10,20,30)
  AND h.viewerID = 50
GROUP BY posterID
```

Comment: Thank you. I switched the second field in your SELECT to COUNT(posterID) (as this is what I needed) - and it works great.
I didn't know before that you can put fields in the SELECT that are not from the table in FROM (but are from the table in JOIN) - though it makes sense.